# Is there a reason Java is jumping over fName for Employee2?

Tags: java

I am working on an assignment and most everything is working except I have 2 java files, Employee and EmployeeTest. I have 2 instances of Employee name myEmployee1 and myEmployee2. I am able to input the first name, last name and salary for my Employee1, but it prints the request for the first name for employee 2, but does not let me put anything in because it then jumps directly to the last name for employee 2. I have checked and double checked my code, and all appears correct. Is there something I am missing?

EmployeeTest.java

```
//import scanner
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EmployeeTest { //begin employee test class

    public static void main(String[] args) { //begin main method
                
        //create scanner instance
        //assign input as variable
        Scanner input = new Scanner ( System.in);
        
        //create variables
        String fName;
        String lName;
        double salary;
        
        
        //generate 2 new instance of Employee class
        //assign variable myEmployee1 and myEmployee2 to new instance
        Employee myEmployee1 = new Employee();
        Employee myEmployee2 = new Employee();
        
        ///////////////////////////////////////////
        ////// Begin Employee 1 Section //////////
        /////////////////////////////////////////
        
            //Get Employee1 info
            //assign employee1 info to variables
            System.out.print("Enter first name for employee 1: ");
            fName = input.nextLine(); // get employee1 first name
            
            System.out.print("Enter last name for employee 1: ");
            lName = input.nextLine(); // get employee1 last name
            
            System.out.print("Enter salary for employee 1: ");
            salary = input.nextDouble();
            
            if (salary < 0) {
                salary = 0.00;
            }
            
            
            //set employee1 info
            myEmployee1.setFName(fName);
            myEmployee1.setLName(lName);
            myEmployee1.setSalary(salary);
        
        /////////////////////////////////////////
        ////// End Employee 1 Section //////////
        ///////////////////////////////////////
        
        ///////////////////////////////////////////
        ////// Begin Employee 2 Section //////////
        /////////////////////////////////////////
        
            //Get Employee2 info
            //assign employee2 info to variables
        
            System.out.print("Enter first name for employee 2: ");
            fName = input.nextLine(); // get employee2 first name
            
            System.out.print("Enter last name for employee 2: ");
            lName = input.nextLine(); // get employee2 last name
            
            System.out.print("Enter salary for employee 2: ");
            salary = input.nextDouble();
            if (salary < 0) {
                salary = 0.00;
            }
            
            
            //set employee2 info
            myEmployee2.setFName(fName);
            myEmployee2.setLName(lName);
            myEmployee2.setSalary(salary);
        
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
        ////// End Employee 2 Section //////////
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        
        //display employee1 info to terminal
            System.out.printf("1 - Employee First Name, Last Name, Salary: %s, %s, %.2f", myEmployee1.getFName(), myEmployee1.getLName(), myEmployee1.getSalary());
        //display employee2 info to terminal
            System.out.printf("2 - Employee First Name, Last Name, Salary: %s, %s, %.2f", myEmployee2.getFName(), myEmployee2.getLName(), myEmployee2.getSalary());

///new code
//find if user wants to make changes to user
            System.out.print("Would you like to make changes to any employees? ");
            changeInfo = input.next();
            System.out.println("Which employee would you like to change? ");
            changeEmployee = input.nextInt();
            
        //either run employee1, employee2 or exit based on users decision to change employee
            if(changeInfo == "true" && changeEmployee == 1) {
                ///////////////////////////////////////////
                ////// Rerun Employee 1 Section //////////
                /////////////////////////////////////////
                
                    //Get Employee1 info
                    //assign employee1 info to variables
                    System.out.print("Enter first name for employee 1: ");
                    fName = input.nextLine(); // get employee1 first name
                    
                    System.out.print("Enter last name for employee 1: ");
                    lName = input.nextLine(); // get employee1 last name
                    
                    System.out.print("Enter salary for employee 1: ");
                    salary = input.nextDouble();
                    input.nextLine(); // used to clear buffer of carriage return after nextDouble
                    
                    //if salary is less than zero, set to 0.00
                    if (salary < 0) {
                        salary = 0.00;
                    }
                    
                    
                    //set employee1 info
                    myEmployee1.setFName(fName);
                    myEmployee1.setLName(lName);
                    myEmployee1.setSalary(salary);
                
                /////////////////////////////////////////
                ////// End Rerun Employee 1 Section /////
                ////////////////////////////////////////
            }
            
            else if(changeInfo == "true" && changeEmployee == 2) {
                ///////////////////////////////////////////
                ////// Rerun Employee 2 Section //////////
                /////////////////////////////////////////
                
                    //Get Employee2 info
                    //assign employee2 info to variables
                
                    System.out.print("Enter first name for employee 2: ");
                    fName = input.nextLine(); // get employee2 first name
                    
                    System.out.print("Enter last name for employee 2: ");
                    lName = input.nextLine(); // get employee2 last name
                    
                    System.out.print("Enter salary for employee 2: ");
                    salary = input.nextDouble();
                    input.nextLine();
                    
                    
                    //if salary is less than zero, set to 0.00
                    if (salary < 0) {
                        salary = 0.00;
                    }
                    
                    
                    //set employee2 info
                    myEmployee2.setFName(fName);
                    myEmployee2.setLName(lName);
                    myEmployee2.setSalary(salary);
                
                ///////////////////////////////////////////////
                ////// End Rerun Employee 2 Section //////////
                //////////////////////////////////////////////
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Thank you and have a wonderful day!");
            }
            
            //output updated employee info
            //display employee1 info to terminal
                System.out.printf("1 - Employee First Name, Last Name, Salary: %s, %s, %.2f\n", myEmployee1.getFName(), myEmployee1.getLName(), myEmployee1.getSalary());
            //display employee2 info to terminal
                System.out.printf("2 - Employee First Name, Last Name, Salary: %s, %s, %.2f", myEmployee2.getFName(), myEmployee2.getLName(), myEmployee2.getSalary());
            
        
        
        
        
        

    }//end main method

} // end employee test class
```

Employee.java

```
public class Employee { //begin Employee class
    
    private String fName, lName; //access restricted String variables
    private double salary; // access restricted data type double for salary
    
    
    //setter for fName
    public void setFName(String fName) {
        this.fName = fName;
    }
    
    //getter for fName
    public String getFName() {
        return this.fName;
    }
    
    //setter for lName
    public void setLName(String lName) {
        this.lName = lName;
    }
    
    //getter for lName
    public String getLName() {
        return this.lName;
    }
    
    //setter for salary
    public void setSalary(double salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
    //getter for salary
    public double getSalary() {
        return this.salary;
    }
        

}//end Employee class
```

Output

```
Enter salary for employee 1: 20000
Enter first name for employee 2: james
Enter last name for employee 2: green
Enter salary for employee 2: 10000
1 - Employee First Name, Last Name, Salary: lee, bron, 20000.00
2 - Employee First Name, Last Name, Salary: james, green, 10000.00

Would you like to make changes to any employees? true
Which employee would you like to change? 
1
Thank you and have a wonderful day!
1 - Employee First Name, Last Name, Salary: lee, bron, 20000.00
2 - Employee First Name, Last Name, Salary: james, green, 10000.00
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: We need to see more code than this: the whole body that includes where you get `employee1`, and ideally, also the `Employee` class.

Answer (score 1):

```java
        System.out.print("Enter salary for employee 1: ");
        salary = input.nextDouble();
        input.nextLine(); // <---

        if (salary < 0) {
            salary = 0.00;
        }
```

`nextDouble` is only going to grab a number, leaving an extra carriage return in buffer. You can clear it with a `nextLine`.

Comment: Thanks Leo. That fixed the issue. I added one more code section and it does not rerun the input section.It runs my else clause regardless of the inputs. Could you give it a look?

Comment: @LeeBaldwin In Java you probably will never do `changeInfo == "true"`. This means comparing the object id of `changeInfo` with the object id of `"true"`, which is always false. Try `changeInfo.equals("true")` instead.

Comment: That got it. Thanks.